# How can I e-mail or share a python .exe fiile zipped or unzipped without triggering safety?

Tags: python, compilation, share, exe, email-attachments

I have created a dictionary-scraper that scraps some words from wiktionary.org. I have compiled it as .exe. It works fine but when I try to e-mail it or share it with some people that can not be done because of safety reasons. After the first try, I was notified that this was due to .exe because .exe files are not likely to be shared. Then I zipped the file but again no e-mailing or sharing was possible. What can I do to share my python programmes with others through e-mail, one drive, google drive etc?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options, you could encrypt your zip or whatever, and warnings do not occur in all .exe files, it depends on what its signature is and other variants which make it "detected".
It's not difficult to pass that security barrier.

- Encrypt
- Alter code
- Hide .exe under other file

and a lot more options.